# VBA Excel Copiar Dados Diversas Planilhas

Tags: vba

Preciso copiar dados de centenas de planilhas e colar em outra (ordenado por data) para apresentar um relatório aos clientes.

Basicamente, tenho todas essas planilhas em uma pasta, e hoje preciso abrir uma a uma para pegar as seguintes informações:

1. data do relatório (planilha) que foi aberto
2. total de títulos vencidos
3. total de títulos a vencer
4. patrimônio
5. provisão de perda contabilizada

E trazer esses dados e colar os itens 2 a 5 na linha e coluna certas, de acordo com a data (1) na planilha que centralizamos essas informações.

O código que tentei até agora (chega a abrir arquivo, mas dá erro na hora de salvar os dados da planilha aberta na planilha destino) é o abaixo:

```
Sub importa_arquivos3()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim shtatual As Worksheet
Dim planatual As Workbook
Dim WNew As Workbook
Dim ArqParaAbrir As Variant
Dim a As Integer, b As Integer
Dim NomeArquivo As String
Dim dataPosicao As Date, dataPlanilha As Date
Dim pdd As Variant
Dim vencidos As Variant
Dim avencer As Variant
Dim rng As Range

'determinando a coluna onde estarão as datas na planilha destino
rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("InfoFIDC").Range("A2:A5000")

'------------------capturar arquivos para tratamento

ArqParaAbrir = Application.GetOpenFilename("Arquivo para importar (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Escolha as pastas de trabalho para importar", MultiSelect:=True)

  If Not IsArray(ArqParaAbrir) Then
   If ArqParaAbrir = "" Or ArqParaAbrir = False Then
    MsgBox "Processo cancelado. Não foi selecionado nenhum arquivo", vbExclamation, "Atenção"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
  End If
End If


'Loop para abrir os arquivos

For a = LBound(ArqParaAbrir) To UBound(ArqParaAbrir)

NomeArquivo = ArqParaAbrir(a)
Application.Workbooks.Open (NomeArquivo)
Set WNew = ActiveWorkbook
Worksheets.Application.Range("A1").Select

              
dataPosicao = Cells.Find("Data de Posição:").Offset(0, 2)
pdd = Cells.Find("PDD").Offset(0, 3)
vencidos = Cells.Find("JPCAPVEN").Offset(0, 3)
avencer = Cells.Find("JPCAPAVE").Offset(0, 10)
ActiveWorkbook.Close

'este loop não está funcionando... aqui eu tentei colar os dados das variáveis acima na planilha destino
For b = 1 To rng.Rows
    If (rng(i, 0) <> dataPosicao) Then Next
    Else
        rng(i, 10).Value = pdd
        rng(i, 8).Value = avencer
        rng(i, 9).Value = vencidos
    End If
Next

WNew.Close False
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

creio que o erro está aqui

```
For b = 1 To rng.Rows
```

rng.Rows é um Range e nao um int.

deduzo que o objectivo seja iterar por todas as linhas do range, ou seja

```
rngRowNumber = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("InfoFIDC").Range("A2:A5000").Rows.Count
For b = 1 To rngRowNumber 
   ....
next
```

Comment: Olá Luis tudo bem? Obrigado pelo comentário, mas acredito que além deste há outros erros no código. Alterei conforme informou, porém agora está me dando erro de Application-defined or object-defined error nas primeiras linhas dentro do loop.. primeiro deu erro que o Next não tinha um "For".. troquei para o While e apareceu outro erro..''' While b <= rngRowNumber
        If (rng(b, 0) = dataPosicao) Then
            rng(b, 10).Value = pdd
            rng(b, 8).Value = avencer
            rng(b, 9).Value = vencidos
        End If
        b = b + 1
    Wend'''
    '''

Comment: esta parte   If (rng(i, 0) <> dataPosicao) Then Next  nao me parece bem. coloca somente   If (rng(i, 0) <> dataPosicao), ou seja se esta codicao for verdadeira nao faz nada, se for falsa executa o restante codigo

Comment: Oi Luis tudo bem? Alterei este item, mas o erro persiste